# I want to add multiple image attribute in product page admin section, but don't mix with product image

Tags: php, magento

I want to add image for option please see attachment here option is a sub part of product. How can I do this I don't want to mix option image with product image.

[image]

Comment: you have to create new attribute and then assign that attribute to option group

Comment: I have already try but this is showing in image section and option image only for option not for product image.